# Почему раскрывающийся список остается пустым, хотя переменная инициализирована

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rest, axios

Изучаю Vue js, возникла необходимость инициализировать массив (listProductType) с помощью запроса на бекэнд до открытия страницы с последующим отображением в виде раскрывающегося списка. Переменная инициализирована, в консоль выходит, но список остается пустым.

Просьба сказать что я делаю не так, где ошибка?

HTML:

```
    <div id="sendForm">
    <div class="productTypeBlock">
        <p><b>Введите тип продукта</b></p>
        <input id="idProductType" v-model="nameOfProductType" placeholder="Введите тип продукта">
        <button id="sendProductType" @click="getAlert">Сохранить</button>
    </div>
    <div class="productCategoryBlock">
        <p><b>Выберите тип продукта</b></p>
        <select>
            <option selected="selected" disabled>Выберите тип продукта</option>
            <option v-for='index in listProductType'>{{index.id}} / {{index.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#sendForm",
    data:{
        nameOfProductType: "",
        listProductType: []
    },
    beforeCreate:() => {
        new Promise((resolve, _) => {
            axios
            .get('http://localhost/admin/getListProductType')
            .then(response => {
                resolve(this.listProductType = response.data);
                console.log(listProductType);
                });
        })
    },
    methods:{
        getAlert(){
            var productType = {
                    name: this.nameOfProductType
                };
            //console.log(productType)
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/admin/addProductType',
                data: productType
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не используйте стрелочные функции в свойствах экземпляра и в коллбэках, например created: () => console.log(this.a)

Помогло:

```
beforeMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost/admin/getListProductType')
    .then(response => {
        this.listProductType = response.data
    })
}
```